# I'm having trouble with my syntax tree and wanted some help for a project!

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, word-classes, phrase-structure, clauses

I have to include null complementizers if they exist as well as any mission NP covert subjects.
This is my sentence:

The woods, always a menace even in the past, had triumphed in the end.

i've been struggling so much with it i would appreciate it if i had the tree diagram

Thank you!

Comment: Better check to see if syntax-tree questions are on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

"Always a menace" would be analysed as a reduced relative clause postmodifying "the woods". The adverbial "even in the past" being a FocP can be disputed though.

Comment: thank you morphosyntax, Yes im actually a bot confused on FocP is there another structure rule that can used in replacement for it? for example i have been using such rules like s --> NP Predp      NP--> (det) N' im not familar with DP , CP and FocP rules

Comment: @Morphosyntax: What did you use to make this tree? Its' beautiful!!

Comment: I adopted Bayer's (1996) approach of treating the focus adverb as a minor functional head. You could treat it as an adjunct, probably adjoining to the PP "in the past". To preserve the endocentricity of the X-bar schema, every head projects its own phrase, so there's the Determiner Phrase (DP) headed by a determiner, which selects an NP. A Complementizer Phrase (CP) is a clausal constituent headed by COMP, much like the S in your schema.

Comment: @axme100 I used this Java application called TreeForm. It's really handy.